# Trying to stop counting clicks after timer is finished

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get my button to stop counting clicks after a 10 second count down timer has finished but I don't know how to stop it properly.

When I try to use:
if (seconds < 1)

Then it just comes up with this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: 
  seconds is not defined
  at onClick ((index):60)
  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):18)
onClick @ (index):60
onclick @ (index):18
```

Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code so far:

```
<body>
<p align="center">
<button class="button" style="width:500px;height:200px;" id="submit2" onClick="onClick()" align="center">Click me!</button>
</p>

<div id="countdowntimertxt" class="countdowntimer" align="center">00:00</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var sTime = new Date().getTime();
var countDown = 10; // Number of seconds to count down from.        

function UpdateCountDownTime() {
    var cTime = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = cTime - sTime;
    var timeStr = '';
    var seconds = countDown - Math.floor(diff / 1000);
    if (seconds >= 0) {
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor( (seconds-(hours*3600)) / 60);
        seconds -= (hours*3600) + (minutes*60);
        if( hours < 10 ){
            timeStr = "" + hours;
        }
        if( minutes < 10 ){
            timeStr = timeStr + ":0" + minutes;
        }else{
            timeStr = timeStr + ":" + minutes;
        }
        if( seconds < 10){
            timeStr = timeStr + ":0" + seconds;
        }else{
            timeStr = timeStr + ":" + seconds;
        }
        document.getElementById("countdowntimertxt").innerHTML = timeStr;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("countdowntimertxt").style.display="none";
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}
UpdateCountDownTime();
var counter = setInterval(UpdateCountDownTime, 500);

var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    if (seconds < 1) {
        clearInterval(clicks)
    }else{
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    }
};
</script>

<p align="center">Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, `seconds` isn't defined, you define it in another function ?

Comment: onClick() doesn't have access to seconds variable !

Comment: But I don't know what to use so that I can make the counting stop when the timer is done, I don't know what variable I should use instead of seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var sTime = new Date().getTime();
var countDown = 10; // Number of seconds to count down from.        
var seconds;
function UpdateCountDownTime() {
    var cTime = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = cTime - sTime;
    var timeStr = '';
    seconds = countDown - Math.floor(diff / 1000);
    if (seconds >= 0) {
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor( (seconds-(hours*3600)) / 60);
        seconds -= (hours*3600) + (minutes*60);
        if( hours < 10 ){
            timeStr = "" + hours;
        }
        if( minutes < 10 ){
            timeStr = timeStr + ":0" + minutes;
        }else{
            timeStr = timeStr + ":" + minutes;
        }
        if( seconds < 10){
            timeStr = timeStr + ":0" + seconds;
        }else{
            timeStr = timeStr + ":" + seconds;
        }
        document.getElementById("countdowntimertxt").innerHTML = timeStr;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("countdowntimertxt").style.display="none";
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}
UpdateCountDownTime();
var counter = setInterval(UpdateCountDownTime, 500);

var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    if (seconds < 1) {
        clearInterval(clicks)
    }else{
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    }
};
```

```html
<p align="center">
<button class="button" style="width:500px;height:200px;" id="submit2" onClick="onClick()" align="center">Click me!</button>
</p>

<div id="countdowntimertxt" class="countdowntimer" align="center">00:00</div>

<p align="center">Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
</p>
```

`var seconds` should be Global variable.

Comment: @Meedie It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You define `seconds` inside of `UpdateCountDownTime()` but also access it in `onClick`.  The value in `onClick` (since we are running in non-strict mode) will be on the global scope and be `undefined`.  Since `undefined < 1` will always evaluate to `false`, then the interval will never be cleared from a click.

You might try adding a `var seconds` outside of `UpdateCountDownTime` and then update that, i.e.

```
var sTime = new Date().getTime();
var countDown = 10; // Number of seconds to count down from.        
var seconds = 10; // Number of remaining seconds
function UpdateCountDownTime() {
    var cTime = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = cTime - sTime;
    var timeStr = '';
    seconds = countDown - Math.floor(diff / 1000);
```

Comment: it now says instead:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: onClick is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):18)
onclick @ (index):18`

Comment: as shown above, you need to move the script above the HTML element so that it is defined